# PHP string manipulation - manipulate date string in PHP for uploading to mysql

Tags: php, regex, string

My String:

```
10:44 13/7
```

What I require:

```
2012-07-13
```

Is there a way I can do this??? The year will always be the current year.

At present, I have:

```
$string = '10:44 13/7';
$string = explode("/", $string);
$date = date('Y') . '-' . $string[0] . '-'. $string[1];
```

Many thanks

Thanks to itsme for solution:

```
        $updated = explode(" ", $updated);
        $updated[1] = explode("/", $updated[1]);

        $y = date('Y');
        $m = $updated[1][1];
        $d = $updated[1][0];

        $updated = $y . '-' . $m . '-' . $d;

        echo $updated;
```

I think rating this question down is a bit harsh... Some of us are not as pro at string manipulation as others and are just getting to grips with PHP. If you want to mark this question down, maybe stackoverflow is not for you or you should just go and try answering the hardcore questions as opposed to making people trying to learn feel small. Yes you know who you are.

Comment: I don't know how to separate the 10:44 from the 13

Comment: You can do it the same way you explode the `/`, try this `$string = explode(" ", $string);`

Comment: @arkascha - I think rating this question down is a bit harsh... Some of us are not as pro at string manipulation as others and are just getting to grips with PHP. If you want to mark this question down, maybe stackoverflow is not for you or you should just go and try answering the hardcore questions as opposed to making people trying to learn feel small.

Comment: @gravy: I did not want to make you feel small, if you do you did not understand my comment. I voted the question down because of the way it was composed (you changed that in between): you gave a question without providing any details about what your actual problem is. Now how do you want people to answer that ? Asking good questions is vital for the quality of this site. Posting a good question implies to make the problem as accurate and clear as possible, so that readers don't have to guess your problem but can actually help you.

Comment: @arkascha - I shortened the question to make it plain and simple for people to understand. Also, I didn't want to initially tell people what I had tried for the simple reason that I wanted to know the best practice way of solving the problem - not just a hacked solution based on my own attempt. I think that StackOverflow is about helping each other to solve programming problems - not about justifying why we cannot solve them and providing documentary evidence to support the fact that a serious attempt has been made before asking the question. Once again, help is welcome, snide comments r not.

Comment: @gravy: sorry to tell you, but what you say does not make sense. You did not 'shorten' the question, there was no usable description in the begin. Asking the best practice is fine, but then do that. StackOverflow is about helping people. But also about investing own power to post GOOD questions instead of throwing something to the masses and hope someone picks it. You really want to tell me you could not pose a better description of your problem right away ? Sorry, dont buy that. You are trying to justify yourself afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

Probably a shorter way, but this will work for you:

```
$string = '10:44 13/7';

list($junk, $date) = explode(' ', $string);
list($day, $month) = explode('/', $date);
$full_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(date('Y') . "-{$month}-{$day}"));
echo $full_date; //2012-07-13
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant way, but it should work:

```
$string = "10:44 13/7/" + date("y");
echo date("y-m-d", strtotime($string));
```

Comment: be careful with your day/month ordering in your date string